# Group and powers

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory

For all $ n \in \mathbb{N}-\{0,1 \}$ is there a group $G_n$ such that for all $ 1 < m \leq n$ there is $ x \in G-\{e \}$ such that $x^m = e$ ?

$e = $ neutral element in $G$.

I think its false, even for small $n$ like $n=3$ , its just a hunch.

I need some hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is: just take $G_n = S_n$, and for $m \leq n$, take the cycle $(1\,2\,\ldots\,m)$.

Comment: What is $S_n$ ?

Comment: @Ahmad, $S_n$ is the *permutation group on $n$ letters*. That is, $S_n$ is the group of bijections of the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. The cycle notation used in my answer is explained for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation).

Comment: Thanks, great help.